# Comparing rows in dataset based on a specific column to find min/max

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dataset

So I have a `dataset` that contains history of a specific tag from a start to end date. I am trying to compare rows based on the a date column, if they're similar by month, day and year, I'll add those to a temporary list by the value of the next column and then once I have those items by similar date, I'll take that list and find the `min/max` values subtract them, then add the result to another list and empty the `temp_list` to start all over again.

**For the sake of time and simplicity, I am just presenting a example of 2D List. Here's my example data**

```
dataset = [[1,5],[1,6],[1,10],[1,23],[2,4],[2,8],[2,12],[3,10],[3,20],[3,40],[4,50],[4,500]]
```

Where the first column will act as `dates` and second `value`.

The issues I am having is :

1. I cant seem to compare every row based on its first column which would take the  value in the second column and include it in the temp list to perform min/max operations?
2. Based on the above 2D List I would expect to get `[18,8,30,450]` but the result is `[5,4,10]`

```
dataset = [[1,5],[1,6],[1,10],[1,23],[2,4],[2,8],[2,12],[3,10],[3,30],[3,40],[4,2],[4,5]]
temp_list = []
daily_total = []
for i in range(len(dataset)-1):
    if dataset[i][0] == dataset[i+1][0]:
        temp_list.append(dataset[i][1])
    else:
        max_ = max(temp_list)
        min_ = min(temp_list)
        total = max_ - min_
        daily_total.append(total)
        temp_list = []
            
print([x for x in daily_total])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
tmp = {}
for d, v in dataset:
    tmp.setdefault(d, []).append(v)

out = [max(v) - min(v) for v in tmp.values()]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[18, 8, 30, 450]
```

Comment: if the date is in the form "Wed Jul 21 21:33:34 CDT 2021" as type java.util.date and i care only about month day year as comparing would this still be valid?

Comment: @Musclemania05 No, you need to parse the date first. Look at the https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

dataset = [
    [1, 5],
    [1, 6],
    [1, 10],
    [1, 23],
    [2, 4],
    [2, 8],
    [2, 12],
    [3, 10],
    [3, 20],
    [3, 40],
    [4, 50],
    [4, 500],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(dataset)
df.columns = ["date", "value"]
df = df.groupby("date").agg(min_value=("value", "min"), max_value=("value", "max"))
df["res"] = df["max_value"] - df["min_value"]
df["res"].to_list()
```

Output:

```
[18, 8, 30, 450]
```

Comment: This answer is also valid thanks for this